Why do the spectral sequences associated to a double complex not always collapse at the second page?
In 'A User's Guide to Spectral Sequences' John McCleary introduces two spectral sequences induced by natural filtrations on a double complex. Let $K^{*,*}$ be a double complex with differentials $d'$ and $d''$ of bidegree $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, respectively. By considering the total degree, defining the differential $d=d' + d''$ and considering one of the two natural filtrations $K_p := \bigoplus_{r \geq p}K^{r,s}$, we obtain a filtered differential graded module. Its associated spectral sequence has as $r$th page
$$E^p_r := Z^p_r/(dZ^{p-r+1}_{r-1} + Z^{p+1}_{r-1}),\quad r,p \geq 0,$$
where $Z^p_r$ denotes the submodule of the elements in $K_p$ mapped into $K_{p+r}$ by $d$. Using that $d'$ and $d''$ have the bidegree specified above we can write
$$Z_r^p= Z(K_p)+K_{p+r}+Z''(K_{p+r-1}),$$
for $r \geq 1$ and if we set $Z(K_p)=\ker d \cap K_p, Z''(K_p)=\ker d'' \cap K_p$.
But this means that for $r \geq 2$ we have
$$Z^{p+1}_{r-1}=Z(K_{p+1})+K_{p+r}+ Z''(K_{p+r-1}),$$
$$dZ^{p-r+1}_{r-1}=dK_{p+r}+d(Z''(K_{p+r-1})),$$
and hence
$$E^p_r=Z(K_p)/(Z(K_{p+1})+dK_{p+r}+d(Z''(K_{p+r-1})))=Z(K_p)/Z(K_{p+1})\text{.}$$
This is independent of $r$ so the spectral sequence should collapse at the second page.
I don't believe this to be true since I have not found any comparable result anywhere, but also I do not see where I am going wrong.

Yeah spectral sequences definitely don't always collapse on the second page
